# Dimension of a polynomial vector subspace by induction.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces, induction

I have to solve this problem by induction.

> Let $k$ be a field and $V(d,n)$ a vector subspace of the $k$-vector space $k[X_{1},\dots,X_{n}]$ consisting on the forms of degree $d$.
>
> See that $\dim_{k}V(d,1)=1$, $\dim_{k}V(d,2)=d+1$, $\dim_{k}V(d,3)=\frac{(d+1)(d+2)}{2}$ and prove by induction that $\dim_k V(d,n)={d+n-1 \choose n-1}$.

This is what I got until now:

- Clearly a basis for $V(d,1)$ is $\{X_1^d\}$.
- A basis for $V(d,2)$ is $\{X_1^{d-j} X_2 ^{j}\}$ and I see that there are $d+1$ combinations.

And this is where I get stuck:

- A basis for $V(d,3)$ is $\{X_1^{d-i-j} X_2^i X_3^j\}$. Is this a correct way to write it? How can I deduct from this that $\dim_{k}V(d,3)=\frac{(d+1)(d+2)}{2}$?
- I am terribly bad at proving by induction. What is the relation between $\dim_k V(d,n-1)$ and $\dim_k V(d,n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction here is just an overkill... This is a direct consequence of the "stars and bars" argument in combinatorics: break $d$ as a sum of $n$ non-negative terms: [Wikipedia: Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars)).

If you *must* use induction... the inductive step ($n\to n+1$) looks like this:

$$V(d,n+1)=\sum_{i=0}^{d}V(i,n)=\sum_{i=0}^{d}{{i+n-1}\choose{n-1}}={{n-1}\choose{n-1}}+\sum_{i=1}^{d}\left({{i+n}\choose{n}}-{{i-1+n}\choose{n}}\right)={{n-1}\choose{n-1}}+\left({{d+n}\choose{n}}-{n\choose{n}}\right)={{d+n}\choose{n}}$$

as required. Note we've used the binomial coefficient identity ${x\choose y}+{x\choose{y+1}}={{x+1}\choose{y+1}}$, and note that this made it possible to cancel out most of the terms in the above sum (except for the first and the last one).

The very first equality above is due to the fact that $X_n$ can have degree $d,d-1,\ldots,0$ so the sum of the degrees of the other variables (denoted by $i$ and summed over) is, again, $0,1,2,\ldots,d$.

Answer (score 1):

You have already noticed that $V(d,n)$ is the span of all possible monic monomials of degree $d$, so you have to count how many of them there are (its not difficult to see they're linearly independent).

Then use as inductive hypothesis that $\dim_k V(d,n-1)={d+n-2\choose n-2}$ **for every $d\ge 0$**, since you want to prove
$$\dim_k V(d,n)={d+n-1\choose n-1}$$
also **for every $d \ge 0$**.

Try to count the number of monic monomials of degree $d$ from $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ if you know the number of monic monomials of degree $d-1$ and $d$ (and whatever degree you need) from $k[X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]$. (Those numbers are, just to be clear, ${d+n-3\choose n-2}$ and ${d+n-2\choose n-2}$.)

Even more: I don't think you will need this, but just in case (or for another time), remember that the inductive hypothesis tells you that there are ${d+n-2\choose n-2}$ monic monomials of degree $d$ in $k[X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]$, but also in $k[X_2,\ldots,X_{n}]$, in $k[X_1,X_3,X_4,\ldots,X_n]$ and so.

Just as an example: supose you want to count for $n=5$ and $d=3$. You have monomials with and without $X_5$. Those without $X_5$ are actually the same that the monomials for $d=3$ and $n=4$; those with $X_5$ can be:

- $X_{i_1}X_{i_2}X_5$, $i_1,i_2 \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, so you can count how many there are in the case $d=2$ and $n=4$;
- $X_i X_5^2$, $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, so you can count how many there are in the case $d=1$ and $n=4$; and finally
- $X_5^3$, which adds only one more element.

Notice that only the formula for $n=4$ is needed, but for several different values of $d$.